# Which tense is correct? Or are they both correct?

Tags: tenses

The last few meetings HAVE BEEN good. 
The last few meetings WERE good.

Comment: I detect no difference.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("no research / ELL"). Hi Matt, it's important to look up a grammar book or a web page on tenses before you ask this kind of question here, as it will often provide the solution. Our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "Be sure to [mention the research you've done](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5043) and what you're still hoping to learn!" For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine.

The difference (as usual for this sort of question) is in how the speaker is choosing to set the temporal focus.

"Have been" implies some relevance to the present, though it does not spell out what that relevance is. It might be that the meetings are being presented as part of a process that is still continuing; or that the outcome of the meetings is still being felt; or other possibilities.

"Were" does not have this implication. It does not rule out a present relevance, but the speaker is choosing not to mention it or give it any focus.